# Rails | 2 checkbox in dom not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have a form in my page and there I have checkboxes.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 p-l-0">
<input type="checkbox" name="q[group_name_eq_any][]" id="tour" value="Tour"> 
<label for="tour">Tour</label>
</div>
```

I use this checkbox in both on the page and the bootstrap modal in small devices.

```
<div class='col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3 hidden-xs'>
          <%= render 'search_filters' %>
</div>

..
<div class="modal-content modal-main-index">
      <%= render 'search_filters' %>
    </div>
..
```

Ofcourse because of this, I have 2 checkboxes with the same id. So one of them can not be clicked. What is the best way to solve this. (I do not want to fill modal on button click with js return)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ofcourse because of this, I have 2 checkboxes with the same id. So one
>   of them can not be clicked. What is the best way to solve this.

Use `class` instead of `id`

```
<div class="col-xs-6 p-l-0">
  <input type="checkbox" name="q[group_name_eq_any][]" class="tour" value="Tour"> 
  <label for="tour">Tour</label>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I ve done. But checkbox can not be clicked. <div class="col-xs-6 p-l-0">
                   <input type="checkbox" name="q[group_name_eq_any][]" id="q_group_name_eq_any_" value="Tour" class="tour"> 
                   
                   <label for="tour">Tour</label>
                   </div>. Id is generated by rails. The original code is  <%= check_box_tag('q[group_name_eq_any][]', "Tour", !params[:q].nil? && !params[:q][:group_name_eq_any].nil? ? params[:q][:group_name_eq_any].include?('Tour') : false, class: 'tour') %>

Answer (score 0):

On the html [label](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) tag

> Tip: A label can be bound to an element either by using the "for" attribute, or by placing the element inside the  element.

Thus, if you have an html page like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="col-xs-6 p-l-0">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q[group_name_eq_any][]" value="Tour">&nbsp;Tour
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 p-l-0">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q[group_name_eq_any][]" value="Tour">&nbsp;Tour
      </label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

both of those check boxes are selectable by clicking on the text. Whereas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="col-xs-6 p-l-0">
      <input type="checkbox" name="q[group_name_eq_any][]" id="tour" value="Tour">_
      <label for="tour">Tour</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 p-l-0">
      <input type="checkbox" name="q[group_name_eq_any][]" id="tour" value="Tour">_
      <label for="tour">Tour</label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

will only ever toggle one of them (the top one in my case).